# Why upgrading Magento 1.5.1.0 to 1.6.0.0 fails?

Tags: magento

Some time ago I upgraded a Magento store 1.4.2.0 to version 1.5.1.0, and the upgrade process was ok. I got some bug/errors though and would like to upgrade Magento to 1.6.0.0, as it is a stable release now.

I downloaded magento 1.6 and followed the installation process, using the old database. After the screen where I type my database acess data, I got an Magento report. It says:

> "Error in file:
>   "/home/italo/www/mage_powershop/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php"
>   - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate
>   entry '0' for key 'son_id'"

I tried also install magento 1.6.0.0 in a new database and then import data from old database, but I got the same problem. (Actually, almost the same, as the key wasn't 'son_id', but it always change anyway...) The installation in a new database runs fine. I tried to use the Magento Repair Database Tool, but it returned a error.

Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working on!

I just disabled the foreign keys and unique checks. In the /app/etc/config.xml file I changed the initStatements node from:

```
<initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
```

to:

```
<initStatements>SET NAMES utf8; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;</initStatements>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your data stored in tables. 
In Magento tables is no index with name "son_id". Maybe any custom module added some fields to Magento core tables and added new indexes. In this case you can not upgrade automatically.

Find table with index named "son_id" and look at data in this field. Maybe you can modify this data to unique values to upgrade...

Comment: Tried that and I didn't find it. I tried searching for 'son_id' and also for the other keys I got before, but no one of them was there. (Someone just posted about this in the Magento Forum: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/242890/ )

Comment: I just found the son_id, my bad! Though I already got this working on. Anyway, thanks a lot for answering. =)